# To Display the Google map on the emmulator

Tags: android, google-maps

Now I am working on the Google maps API. I am not able to display the map on the emulator as well as the device......... how can i dis play the map.

I tried like this but i failed...

1. I searched for the debug.keystore in c:/ i found it.
2. I got Keytool.exe from the `"C:\Program Files\Java\<JDK_version_number>\bin"`.
3. Opened the commend prompt and went to the above folder.
4. After that i copied this

`"keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass  android -keypass android"`

and pressed enter then I got the Google api key `**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**`

I pasted the key in this site `http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html.`

but the map is not generated it is saying that

`fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint.`

What i need to do now to get the Map API key.

Comment: check out this link [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)

Comment: Just follow the tutorial on this link http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Answer (score 54):

Okay, I was able to solve the problem in my case. I've got Java 7 on my machine and when I followed all the instructions as they are, I've got a SHA1 fingerprint, not MD5. I tried to use it to get the key and received exactly the error message from which this thread has started.

If you are having the same problem, just add the -v option (verbose output) after -list. keytool will then give you the MD5 fingerprint as well - use it.

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

I will try to let Android folks know that they need to update the page with instructions.

Comment: Well played, didn't notice but it does say SHA1 instead of MD5, easy to miss.  -v gives both in its output and the MD5 worked!

Answer (score 2):

for JDK 1.7 you get SHA1 fingerprint by default. But for generating Google Map API key you need fingerprint of MD5.
For more details navigate through the below link.

[How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you're supposed to enter in the link you posted is the MD5 fingerprint of your android SDK debug certificate. To get this you navigate here

Windows Vista: C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore

Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\.android\debug.keystore

and then enter

```
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

What you're currently doing is navigating to your Java folder and trying to find the fingerprint for your android SDK debug certificate there. It isn't located in that folder and hence you end up with a blank fingerprint `::*:::*:::*:::*:::*:*`

You need to find the .android folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. have you checked the path you use? I mean "C:\android\debug.keystore", Does the file there?
2. have you compared your fingerprint (the result of keytool.exe calling) with the example on http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html  page? they must be very similar, maybe you just copied not the whole fingerprint from the cmd

Comment: thanks for the immediate response...It is debug.keystore is there in the c:/android...And also i copy enter key of 32 digits   **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**. but still i am getting the same i tried just now also

Comment: thanku Alek i got the key now...still the map is not visible in the emulator what to do..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to generate MD5 signature.

- Find the folder .android which contains debug,keystore(usually it is located in c:\Documents and Settings\"User Name".android
- Oepn command prompt and go to the keytool folder that you mentioned.
- Now use following easy command to key MD5 fingerprint.

  keytool -list -keystore "c:\Documents and Settings\"User Name".android\debug.keystore"
- press Enter. It will ask you for password again press enter.
- Enter the generated key in Google API registration page.
- Use this key in your MapView.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem but got fixed...the problem might be you.. might have not given default location for emulator..i will get u the proper way to get the map in emulator...

1)to generate the hash key
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

2)to set the default location

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#device_installation

hope it works fine..