# How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?

Tags: android, google-maps, md5, sha1, fingerprint

As I want to use Google maps in my application, I need the debug certificates' MD5 fingerprint. I tried following.:

(Here I copied the debug.keystore file from C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android in bin folder)

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

But got the following results:

```
androiddebugkey, May 27, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): "some code"
```

However that is not working to get MAP API key. Is SHA1 is same as MD5?

What should I do to get the MD5 certificate?

Answer (score 195):

With JDK 1.7 installed, keytool always outputs by default SHA1 fingerprint, not MD5. 
you can get the MD5 Certificate by adding -v option.

use the following code:-

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -v -list -alias
androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

it will output MD5 certificate as well.

Comment: Now MD5 & sha1 process changed Google After we got MD5 here.we need to get API key from Google API console right. thanks guys

Comment: @Ankit-Saxena - Can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336382/md5-missing-from-keytool-command-when-fired-for-apk/

-v option is not working with me.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, the "-v" option [no more prints MD5](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8249541) for JDK 8 and newer.

Answer (score 27):

To get MD5 value and SHA1...etc fallow this below:

Before this dont forget to copy the debug.keystore to a folder Androidkeystore like that created in C drive.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin>keytool -v -list -keystore C:\Androidkeyst
ore\debug.keystore
```

it asks here..
Enter keystore password: android

enter you got here MD5 & SHA1..etc

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains ? entry

Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: ?? ???, ????
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[?]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 67b6344b
Valid from: Mon Jun 18 20:33:56 IST 2012 until: Wed Jun 11 20:33:56 IST 2042
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  C2:61:51:3E:BC:C8:0C:DB:75:B6:E7:C4:90:AD:91:39
         SHA1: CD:5E:8A:0F:4E:0F:2E:FD:92:5E:5E:4R:CF:F8:44:33:2C:8C:B8:97
         SHA256: B5:BF:75:60:DB:62:09:49:F1:38:CH:49:18:22:18:95:03:C9:5C:14:F6:
B0:F4:21:D2:19:B8:FF:38:D2:B9:FD
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
```

NOTE: if there are any spaces in the directory path you MUST enclose it in quotes.  e.g. use this format:

-keystore "C:\Users\Your Name\.android\debug.keystore"

Comment: @AnkitSaxena This answer is better and helped me so please do not stop anyone from providing an alternative answer with different information. Thanks K.krishnan for this answer +1

Answer (score 18):

Hello in the year 2021.

The keytool of JDK 8 and newer does not print MD5 anymore, even if you try the standard suggestion to add the "-v" option to the "keygen -list" command.

I guess MD5 is no more considered secure enough and [has been removed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8249541).

At the same time there are still places like Amazon "Security Profile Management" for LWA etc. requiring you to submit the MD5 signature of your certificate.

Here is a command which will deliver it (use the password "android" for the Android Studio keystore):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | \
openssl dgst -md5
```

And if you want to have colon character inbetween, then add the following "sed" command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | \
openssl dgst -md5 | \
sed 's/[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]/&:/g; s/:$//'
```

The above command works on Linux, macOS and even Windows (in git bash):

[image: git bash screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

If you are using jdk 7:

Use -v option.

Comment: Please note the date that this question was asked. Don't answer old questions unless you think that you have a better answer.

Comment: I just did it because it solve my problem. And I just got the problem now.
I just wanted to left something if anyone comes with the same problem now. By the way thanks for the minus 2 points. :(

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to get **SHA 1,MD 5** is to click on Gradle in the upper hand right side near the corner of the screen of Android Studio. Then click on the name of the app(e.g **android123(root)**: it should appear like this). After that, you will find a **subfolder named android** and clicking on it go for the **signingReport**.It should run in the console and should show you the SHA 1,MD 5. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! All the other answers didn't work for me, but this one did.

Comment: This could be simplified as running `./gradle signingReport`.

Answer (score 4):

add  `-v`

right after `keytool` and before `-list`

```
keytool -v -list
```

Answer (score 3):

copy ' debug.keystore '  file  to  `c:\`    or Some folder

you try going
`c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.25\bin    folder`
and input

`c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.25\bin>keytool -list -keystore c:\debug.keystore`

password  is  'android'

Answer (score 3):

The -v flag gives the SHA1 certification as well. Without that flag you only get the MD5 fingerprint.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem in Windows 8 by opening the Command Prompt (Admin), then type:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -v -list -keystore C:\<Your Path>\<Your Keystore>
```

After that, simply go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/

As they changed to a new interface, you have to go to the ***APIs & auth*** tab on the left side, then go to ***Registered Apps***, select your existing API key to replace it or create a new one, using the SHA1 code generated previously.

That's how I got it working.

Answer (score 2):

As **Paul Crinigan** suggests [here](https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/questions/172414/how-to-apply-api-key-i-cant-find-md5-key-in-certrs.html) you can obtain the **MD5** hash running the following command:

```
keytool -exportcert -v -alias keystore_alias -keystore "path\to\keystore\my.keystore" | openssl dgst -md5
```

where:

- `keystore_alias` is your keystore's alias in case you have one.
- `path\to\keystore\my.keystore` is the path to your keystore file.

After running the command you will be asked for the keystore password in case you have set one. The output will be a hash like this:

```
(stdin)= 8a7b562730f9581c2161bf3984e7af5e
```

The **MD5** will be the output hash inserting the colon `:` symbol every 2 chars:

`8a:7b:56:27:30:f9:58:1c:21:61:bf:39:84:e7:af:5e`

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that JDK 1.7 keytool ALWAYS return SHA1 fingerprint. Look there to solve the problem instead of downgrade your JDK: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19035#makechanges

Answer (score 1):

Simply export your project using your keystore in eclipse and in the last step you will get both SHA-1 and MD-5..

[image]

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657142/how-do-i-generate-my-md5-and-sha1-thumbprints-using-eclipse-for-debug-keystore) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

.Hello in the year 2023.

I have crafted a Java code snippet to generate and display relevant information such as MD5. Feel free to give it a try using the following code:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class KeyStoreInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java KeyStoreInfo <keystore-path> <keystore-password>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String keystorePath = args[0];
        String keystorePassword = args[1];

        try {
           
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(keystorePath);
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
         
            keystore.load(is, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

            Enumeration<String> enumeration = keystore.aliases();
            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                String alias = enumeration.nextElement();
                Certificate certificate = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
                PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

      
                System.out.println("Alias Name: " + alias);
                System.out.println("Public Key: " + publicKey);

          
                System.out.println("Certificate: " + certificate.toString());

                System.out.println("MD5 Fingerprint: " + getFingerprint(certificate, "MD5"));
                System.out.println("SHA-1 Fingerprint: " + getFingerprint(certificate, "SHA-1"));
                System.out.println("SHA-256 Fingerprint: " + getFingerprint(certificate, "SHA-256"));
                System.out.println("---");
            }

            is.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   private static String getFingerprint(Certificate certificate, String algorithm) {
      try {
          MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
          byte[] publicKey = certificate.getEncoded();
          md.update(publicKey);
          byte[] digest = md.digest();

          StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
          for (byte b : digest) {
              String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & b);
              if (hex.length() == 1) hexString.append('0');
              hexString.append(hex);
              hexString.append(":");  
          }
          hexString.deleteCharAt(hexString.length() - 1);
          return hexString.toString().toUpperCase(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return null;
      }
}

}
```

How to use:

1. `javac -encoding UTF-8 KeyStoreInfo.java`
2. `java KeyStoreInfo your_app.keystore_path your_keystore_password`