# Google Maps API for Android, getting SHA1 cert instead of MD5

Tags: android, google-maps, md5, sha1, fingerprint

When I try to get the MD5 fingerprint using `keytool`, I get a SHA1 fingerprint instead and the Google Maps doesn't recognize it. How do I get the MD5 fingerprint?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1
Please check this link. The answer is posted here. Worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696288/androidgoogle-maps-api-key-signup-md5-certification-key

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use JDK version 1.6 instead of 1.7 because 1.7 generates the fingerprint with SHA1 by default.
or you can use (-v) option of the keytool to give you all supported algorithms output and you will find the MD5 in it. for examble : keytool -v -list -keystore [your keystore path] and then enter the password which is [android] by default (you can get the keystore path from Eclipse window>Prefs>Android>build).

Sincerely,
DigitalFox

Comment: I was looking for generating SHA1 key, -v option worked for me and displayed all certificate fingerprints like SHA1, MD5 and other info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, full prove and permanent way to get MD5 or SHA1 or SHA256 is as follows_

1. Update the [PATH Environment Variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).
2. Start Command prompt "Ctrl+R" & enter `cmd` in *RunDailog panel* then click ok.
3. Navigate to the directory where your `debug.keystore` file resides e.g., `C:\Users\Admin\.android` path of my debug.keystore file.
4. Run the following command

   **`C:\<PATH OF YOUR DEBUG.KEYSTORE FILE>>keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -keypass android -storepass android`**

   e.g., 
   C:\Users\Admin.android>keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -keypass android -storepass android

   **`output_`**

   Alias name: androiddebugkey
   Creation date: Sep 20, 2013
   Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
   Certificate chain length: 1
   Certificate[1]:
   Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
   Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
   Serial number: 39ea2d1c
   Valid from: Fri Sep 20 10:55:39 IST 2013 until: Sun Sep 13 10:55:39 IST 2043
   Certificate fingerprints:

   ```
    MD5:  85:46:3B:8A:62:02:1D:DB:B6:BF:A1:9F:45:D4:54:C6
    SHA1: 69:AF:B5:D6:14:ED:0B:31:89:6B:BD:0F:CC:3C:4C:57:CE:4C:A1:BC
    SHA256: 57:7F:DE:25:31:38:4B:7F:4B:F1:96:CB:46:75:FC:34:85:E3:03:15:D3:
   ```

   D7:DE:0E:55:82:1B:21:9F:62:97:4E
        Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
        Version: 3

I hope this will help to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in cmd:

First go on this path : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin

then

Type this command..

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin > **keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\Users\Mitul.android\debug.keystore -keypass android -storepass android**

The blow code will work!
try this to get md5 key

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -
keystore "c:\Users\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -ke
ypass android

instead of path & users administrator give your own

Answer (score 0):

just export your app in eclipse and the MD5 + SHA1 will be displayed in the window. (just before "finish")