# android google map doesn't shows with a debug key

Tags: android, google-maps

I've generated a debug code for my application and registered it with google maps.
but from some reason my map still refuse to show.. i only get a blank map...

I've checked the AndroidMenifest file and it is set up correctly...

some one have an idea what else could i try ??

this is my menifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.WhosAround"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.WhosAround.AppVariables"
        android:icon="@drawable/questionmark"
        android:label="Who&apos;s Around?"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.WhosAround.Activities.Loader"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Map.Map" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure its the correct key? Are you sure you can connect to the internet from the phone?

Comment: yes i've regenerated it and copy pasted it...

Comment: That didn't answer the question, I can easily regenerate a wrong key. How are you sure its the correct key? Can you link to the methode you used for generating the key?

Comment: sure i've used this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Answer (score 0):

So you generated you key with something like this:

```
"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/keytool.exe" -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:/Users/YOURNAME/.android/debug.keystore"
```

and then used password android?

The problem is that you can always generate a key, it doesn't really tell you that you haven't found the correct path (ye keytool is stupid like that).

Comment: yep exactly... and that the only path which i have the debug.keystore at.. and yet it doesn't work..
By the way - i didn't see that keytool always generate a key.. if the file is not a keystore it tells me..

Comment: @AsafNevo and you are sure you have internet on the phone? And you are sure you are building with google maps and not regular android?

Comment: @AsafNevo What do you mean with you "only get a blank map"? Do you mean you get a map with unloaded map tiles (greyish tiles) or do you mean something else?

Comment: i'm sure i have internet enabled because my application uses internet before.. and yes blank is only tiles with nothing in the map... isn't there's some kind of map error that i can see what the error is ?

Comment: the most weird thing is that i generated successfully a HASH key for Facebook from the same debug.keystore

Comment: @AsafNevo Yes but the key you use for facebook is a sha1 while the one for google maps is a md5 key. I'd suggest you give it another try and look here first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7221014/969325