# play youtube in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

please i want way to play youtube video in videoview

I looked at a lot of solutions and pages, but I can not find an answer to this question
Please give me a definite solution to this question

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried...?... check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13814855/2219600

Answer (score 1):

Hay behalf of `VideoView` its much better to use [`Google's YouTube Android Player API`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/), if your need is specific to play `YouTube video`, Using this you can directly embed all of the functionality of YouTube in your application.

You can do it by simply following below steps_

> 1. You should target your application to at least Android 2.2. ( e.g., android:minSdkVersion="8" or API level 8)
> 2. Next you need to [Registering your application to get an API key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register). It's free, you need your Google account to get it. You need SHA1 key of your application that you can [Get SHA1 key for your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165700/google-maps-api-for-android-getting-sha1-cert-instead-of-md5).
> 3. [Download - YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) and Unzip the compressed folder, locate the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar, and add it to your project's /libs folder.
> 4. Add INTERNET to your manifest (`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`)
> 5. That`s all you are completely set to get a ride on. You can find YouTube demo [Sample Applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications),  [youtube - android-player](https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player)
>      .

I hope this will help you and all! :)

Comment: very thanks,but  i want play youtube video specifically in videoview

Comment: but as far as I know u can't monetize videos if u use a youtube player

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has an official [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) specifically designed to play YouTube videos within your applications. You may consider looking at [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) which allows you to easily embed a video player.

Comment: please i want play youtube video specifically in videoview