# Api Key to publish my app with Google Maps to Google Play

Tags: android, api, google-maps, publish

I have an app with Google Maps. The works fine. But when I published my app on Google Play, maps showing whites.

I have read that other Api Key is required to publish the app. But I get not understand how to do this.

Could someone explain step by step how to do it clearly?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see the map on your test device? If yes, then your settings for displaying the map are ok, but then the API key is not valid for the play store, because there is a difference between API Key for Debug Modus and Publishing. Therefore you need get the SHA Fingerprint of your keystore key (Not the Android Debug key -> you need the Publishing keystore key) and add this to the manifest when generating the APK for Google Play store.

Comment: Yes, I see the map on my device. Can you explain the steps to get the SHA to publish?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165700/google-maps-api-for-android-getting-sha1-cert-instead-of-md5

or here: http://hackerspace.lifehacker.com/the-easy-way-to-find-your-md5-and-sha1-in-eclipse-for-a-1505263073

Comment: I have do this: export my project. then in cmd: keytool.exe -list -alias "aliasname" -keystore "keystorepath" -storepass "pass" -keypass "pass"

Comment: and I have get SHA1. I have to create a new API key in Google Console, paste in manifest and publish the apk?

Comment: The SHA1 should be the SHA1 of the keystore which you use for publishing the app. Also dont forget to add your package name after putting the sha1 key in the google console, so liek something like this:

98:31:31....:5H;com.example

Comment: I have the SHA1 to debug. It works fine. But I want to get the Api Key to publish the app in Google Play

Comment: yes, so you have to generate a keystore for publishing the app. you will then use the keystore for getting the SHA1 for your maps api. take a look at there: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/publish-to-android-market--mobile-2744

Comment: I have published my app in Google Play. My problem is Google Maps. I need to know how sign the app correctly