# How to generate MD5 fingerprint

Tags: java, android, keytool

hi i have to generate signing cartificate fingerprint so my first task is to generate keystore file using command.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore myrelease.keystore -alias alias_name.

now i have to generate the finger prints(MD5) using this command:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore helloworld7.keys
>   tore -alias alias_name -validity 10000.

but its giving output in

> Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):my finger print.

its giving finger print using SHA1 algorithm.can any one please tell what modification i have to do in my commands so that i can get MD5 finger prints

Answer (score 1):

add `-v` after `keytool` and you will get all fingerprints

Answer (score 1):

JDK1.6 by default generates MD5 fingerprint but jdk1.7 generates SHA1. But you can get MD5 fingerprint by using `keytool -v -list -keystore your_key` in the keytool commandAs you are using jdk1.7, so you can get MD5 finger print by placing -v -list in the command.
Example:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -v -list -keystore helloworld7.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

Being confronted with the same problem, I have found some posts on the site saying that this happens because of the jdk1.7, it generates SHA1 instead of MD5. I have uninstalled jdk1.7 and installed jdk1.6 and following the Abhi's link(jdk 1.6 is used there also) I was able to get a MD5 fingerprint. I registered it on http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html and I got an API Key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to another post on here with the exact same problem:

[How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

This solution actually works for JDK1.7. I tested it before I posted this.