# Using keytool to get the MD5 signature of a certificate

Tags: java, android, key, keytool

I need to get a Google map key for my application and, for this, I need the MD5 signature of my certificate. As seen on the Internet, I use "keytool" to get it :

```
keytool -list -alias mykey -keystore mykeystore
```

The problem is that the answer is a SHA1 signature instead of an MD5 signature.

I use JDK 1.7.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by going back to java 1.6.

Answer (score 7):

Hello in the year 2021.

The keytool of JDK 8 and newer does not print MD5 anymore, even if you try the standard suggestion to add the "-v" option to the "keygen -list" command.

I guess MD5 is no more considered secure enough and [has been removed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8249541).

At the same time there are still places like Amazon "Security Profile Management" for LWA etc. requiring you to submit the MD5 signature of your certificate.

Here is a command which will deliver it (use the password "android" for the Android Studio keystore):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | \
openssl dgst -md5
```

And if you want to have colon character inbetween, then add the following "sed" command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | \
openssl dgst -md5 | \
sed 's/[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]/&:/g; s/:$//'
```

The above command works on Linux, macOS and even Windows (in git bash):

[image: MinGW screenshot]

Comment: Thanks man!! I really need this. Saved my whole day. You are absolutely correct for JDK 8.

Comment: Amazon really needs to get rid of MD5.  It's a security risk for everyone!  Amazon claims to have cutting edge software but they're really outdated...

Answer (score 3):

There is another Post about this same thing [How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

I guess JDK 1.7 defaults to SHA1. To fix this the following has worked:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -v -list -alias
androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

I tried this, and it worked for me. It gives you MD%, SHA1, SHA256 and Signature Algorithm Name. In that order.

Answer (score 1):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias alias -keypass keypass -keystore ./test.keystore -storepass 123456 | md5sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the keytool command as:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

More on getting Map API Key is Here: http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

### Update:

As you are using JDK 1.7, there is a new command line argument to its keytool, namely -keyalg.

I know you can specify -keyalg RSA, so maybe -keyalg MD5 will give you the right key.

Comment: Not better. The keytool's answer is still a SHA1 signature.

Comment: The use of the -keyalg MD5 parameter doesn't change the result. I desesperately get a SHA1 signature.