# Keytool generates SHA1 fingerprint instead of MD5?

Tags: java, android, md5, sha1, keytool

I want to use Google Maps in my application, I have followed [this](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) tutorial to generate MD5 fingerprint of my eventappkey.keystore. But keytool generates SHA1 fingerprint instead of MD5, due to which I am unable to register for Google Api as google accepts MD5 fingerprint of keystore.

[image: Command line snapshop (Window 7)]

I have looked at other answers which suggest to use jdk1.6. But is there a better way so that I do not need to move to jdk1.6. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

Comment: Here the answer which works in the year 2021 ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286857/165071

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you add the -v (verbose) option to your command line, like

```
keytool -v -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

it should show you the MD5 fingerprint

Answer (score 2):

If use android studio then use this method :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Syntax:

keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Example:


C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_u
ser_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keyp
ass android
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: c:\users\your_
user_name\.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: c:\users\your_user_name\.andr
oid\debug.keystore
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:738)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\sriniv
as\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass an
droid
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Apr 8, 2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 4e7c69e7
Valid from: Wed Apr 08 15:17:20 IST 2015 until: Fri Mar 31 15:17:20 IST 2045
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  9D:C3:05:CB:FF:CA:06:31:8C:FC:FE:44:6C:94:BC:90
         SHA1: 2F:88:EF:9D:1B:3E:35:87:18:7D:56:B5:95:83:9A:EF:C1:B3:25:B4
         SHA256: 0F:D2:BC:2C:58:1B:16:3D:E3:5C:76:7D:C3:49:3A:A0:9D:95:4E:3E:6B:
71:0B:F7:2B:23:72:54:B8:57:62:A2
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3
```