# Having trouble getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate

Tags: android, debugging, certificate, fingerprint

I am having real trouble getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate?

Can anyone please offer any assistance?

I do not have any luck in Command prompt when I follow the instructions in this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the exact problem or error in your question, for example, which command did you try, and what was the output.

A possible issue is that you are running JDK 7 and that shows the SHA1 hash as default instead of an MD5 hash, the thread below could help you in that case.

[How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

Comment: I am running JDK 6 from Windows Vista.
What should I be typing into the command prompt?
Would the issue be my CMD prompt is coming up with C:\> rather than just C:\ ?

Comment: you need to go to your keytool directory if you did not add it to your envirnoment variable path. To make it simple, try the following commands:  navigate to your java home, example "cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin" Then run this command: "keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore" And change the alias name and keystore name