# invalid maps android maps api fingerprint

Tags: android, google-maps

I followed the instructions for getting a maps debug key but got an error saying that the fingerprint I entered was invalid. I entered the following in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Teererai>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Teerer
ai\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

and got the output below:

androiddebugkey, Jun 20, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 75:BD:38:52:6D:03:83:E6:34:F0:3C:88:72:6F:C3:E2:
38:8A:C9:96

But when I tried copying and pasting it into the registration site, I got a message stating that the fingerprint I entered was invalid. Is there something I've done wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for maps api to work you need MD5 fingerprint instead of SHA1. in order to get the MD5 one you need to add the -v option to the command. Please see [How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)