# android api with google map displays grid

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an android application that uses google maps api v2.
I believe I have done everything as google tutorial sais but still I am getting only the google maps grid (no map). I have created a debug key from using SHA1 of keystore.debug.

below are my settings:
Eclipse java compiler version 1.7
Project java compiler version 1.6

application manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="my.app.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/> 
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application>
        <activity>
        ...
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Map xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BackGroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".test" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" >
        </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Map Activity:

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
MapView mapView; 
MapController mc;
      GeoPoint p;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview); 
                mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
                mapView.setStreetView(true);


                mc = mapView.getController();
                String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

                p = new GeoPoint(
                      (int) (lat * 1E6), 
                      (int) (lng * 1E6));

                mc.animateTo(p);
                mc.setZoom(17); 
                mapView.invalidate();
}

      @Override
      protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { return false; }
```

}

I know that there are plenty of post with the same problem. I have read them all!!!
I have created the key several times but still the same...
Any ideas what is wrong and I am only seeing the grid? the application has the same outcome to AVD as well as to a Samsung mobile with android version 2.2.1

Comment: You definitely generated the Key incorrectly this is the main cause of this issue, you need to follow all the steps to generate a key again from the beginning.

Comment: I have generated the key several times in many different ways. I had also installed jdk 1.6 in order to create the key from that version since I had read some posts that was reffering to that. what could possible went wrong to key generation?

Comment: I have also tried to create my own certificate, create a new key from the sha1 of that certificate and sign/export the apk. then I installed the application to my android phone. I still get an empty map with only the grid and the zoom panel. Thus I lean to believe that there is something wrong with the code...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you writing you application for API V2 then you are using the wrong objects, few things you need to fix:

**1.** Remove this:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

it's a permission for Google Map API V1.

**2.** you have to add this 2 permissions:

```
<permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

change: `your.application.package` to your current application package.

**3.** As you targeting `SDK v8`, you have to add fragment support to your application in order to use the `SupportMapFragment` from Google Map API V2, So you need to add `google-support-v4` and change your map object to `SupportMapFragment`.

**4.** Your `MapActivity` has to be changed to `FragmentActivity`.

**5.** You can can get more information on how to make those changes in a blog post I wrote on how to add Google Map API V2 to your project:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: can you also tell me how to manipulate the fragment as I did with mapview? I want to focus the map at a specific location and add a mark.

Comment: please create a new question and I will help you.

Comment: Thats not really nice, what you did right now. I didn't helped you here?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related with the emulator, you need to install to APK's.
I had similar problems so I prepared step by step tutorial to show how you can use google map android v2 on emulator(android 4.2.2) have a look at to my blog: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: Although my question was already answered, thank for the tutorial. It is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate MD5 fingerprint from java keytool instead of SHA1.
Check this post to generate MD5 fingerprint:
[How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

Comment: MD5 is needed for api v1 not for api v2. I have tried it and the google console api was returning an error.