# Implementing View state settings

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view

I have a Fragment which has a button. When creating a Fragment, I want to get a UiSettings instance from the fragment and change whether the button should be shown. You can get the idea looking [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getUiSettings%28%29).
So my code is:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    private Button button;
    private UiSettings settings;

    public getUiSettings(){
        return settings;
    }
}

class UiSettings{
    private boolean showButton = true;
    //setters and getters go here
}
```

My question is how do I trigger button visibility depending on UiSettings, and how do I connect button visibility state to the changes in UiSettings?

Comment: Give us your preference layout ?

Comment: @Flextra there's no preference layout. Please follow the link above to get the idea.

Comment: could it help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549908/android-google-api-failed-to-load-map-fixed

Comment: @Flextra I'm afraid it's 1000 miles away from what I'm looking for.

Comment: i'm sorry, friend. i pass

Comment: Why not make UiSettings a parcelable and pass it in your Fragment? Have your UiSettings hold a reference to it's fragment "holder" and create an apply() method in it that does you need to the fragment elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would override `onResume()` in your `Fragment` and there grab the `UiSettings` instance and apply the value to the function with something like

```
button.setVisibility(uiSettings.showButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

So in total, you would add to your code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    button.setVisibility(uiSettings.showButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

It might also be a good idea to make `UiSettings` a class outside your `Fragment`'s class, and then apply a `public` setter to the `showButton` variable, and in that setter change the visibility of the `Fragment's` button via a some interface that you'd create (essentially data-binding the two).

The interface might look something like

```
public interface Binding {
    dataChanged();
}
```

Then `UiSettings`

```
public class UiSettings {
    public Binding binder;
    private boolean showButton;

    public void setShowButton(boolean showButton) {
        this.showButton = showButton;
        if (binder != null) {
            binder.dataChanged();
        }
    }

    public boolean getShowButton() {
        return showButton;
    }
}
```

And your fragment would then `implement` `Binding` and have added to it

```
@Override
public void dataChanged() {
    button.setVisibility(uiSettings.getShowButton() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```