# Android Google Map V2, Output is not showing

Tags: google-maps, android-emulator, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I tried lot MAP tutorials but mt emulator is showing only a blank window. Even i tried the Google map view sample code its also showing the same. Below is the code i tried, anybody please provide solution for this

**Activity**

```
package info.androidhive.googlemapsv2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

        // Changing map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

        // Showing / hiding your current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

        // Enable / Disable my location button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        // lets place some 10 random markers
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // random latitude and logitude
            double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                    longitude);

            // Adding a marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                    .title("Hello Maps " + i);

            Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                    + randomLocation[1]);

            // changing marker color
            if (i == 0)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (i == 1)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            if (i == 2)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
            if (i == 3)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            if (i == 4)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            if (i == 5)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
            if (i == 6)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            if (i == 7)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
            if (i == 8)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            if (i == 9)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
            if (i == 9) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

/**
 * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
 */
private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

    return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
            longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
            150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

**LAYOUT**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MANIFEST FILE**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBZMlkOv4sj-M5JO9p6wksdax4TEjDVLgo" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**output**

![enter image description here][1]

**CONSOLE**

```
        [2013-09-04 12:21:48 - GoogleMapsV2] ------------------------------
    [2013-09-04 12:21:48 - GoogleMapsV2] Android Launch!
    [2013-09-04 12:21:48 - GoogleMapsV2] adb is running normally.
    [2013-09-04 12:21:48 - GoogleMapsV2] Performing info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity activity launch
    [2013-09-04 12:21:48 - GoogleMapsV2] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '1'
    [2013-09-04 12:21:48 - GoogleMapsV2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '1'
    [2013-09-04 12:21:49 - GoogleMapsV2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
    [2013-09-04 12:21:49 - GoogleMapsV2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
    [2013-09-04 12:22:33 - GoogleMapsV2] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
    [2013-09-04 12:22:33 - GoogleMapsV2] Uploading GoogleMapsV2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
    [2013-09-04 12:22:35 - GoogleMapsV2] Installing GoogleMapsV2.apk...
    [2013-09-04 12:23:32 - GoogleMapsV2] Success!
    [2013-09-04 12:23:32 - GoogleMapsV2] Starting activity info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
    [2013-09-04 12:23:33 - GoogleMapsV2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/.MainActivity }
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] ------------------------------
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] Android Launch!
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] adb is running normally.
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] Performing info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity activity launch
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD '1'
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] ------------------------------
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] Android Launch!
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] adb is running normally.
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] Performing info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity activity launch
    [2013-09-04 12:23:34 - GoogleMapsV2] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD '1'
    [2013-09-04 12:23:36 - GoogleMapsV2] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
    [2013-09-04 12:23:36 - GoogleMapsV2] Starting activity info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
    [2013-09-04 12:23:40 - GoogleMapsV2] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
    [2013-09-04 12:23:40 - GoogleMapsV2] Starting activity info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
    [2013-09-04 12:23:40 - GoogleMapsV2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/.MainActivity }
    [2013-09-04 12:23:40 - GoogleMapsV2] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
    [2013-09-04 12:23:42 - GoogleMapsV2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/.MainActivity }
    [2013-09-04 12:23:42 - GoogleMapsV2] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJKPM.png
```

Comment: your emulator needs google play services. Try to run in device.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine in device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not created your own API key. First you have to generate API key using SHA1 certificate from your keystore than try.

If you want to generate SHA1 Certificate using your keystore than follow this :

[How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

To enable service and for generating key visit :
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

and make sure you enable "Google Maps Android API v2" in the service tab of Google API Console.