# How I get My MD5 and SHA-256?

Tags: android

I need to use both the MD5 and SHA-256 values in amazon account.

Comment: You need to get the MD5 and SHA-256 values, right?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicated from https://stackoverflow.com/q/6305938/3117650. Where you can find the right answer, but is not ticked as right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/3117650) answer for SHA-1

You should:

1. On Android Studio got Terminal window (View > Tool Windows > Terminal);
2. Paste this code `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

And should have something like this
[image]